# R, save image as encrypted file

Tags: r, image, encryption

I sometimes save images of R workspaces as images using a command like:

```
save.image(file = 'imagefilename.RData')
```

Is there a way to do this but save the file as encrypted, perhaps with a password, on the fly? Thx. J.

Comment: You may have a look at CRAN package [**cyphr**](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cyphr), but the easiest is to use a transparent system wide encryption system like Veracrypt or [Boxcryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/). The latter works well with, for example, NextCloud and Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example for package **cyphr** taken from the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cyphr/vignettes/cyphr.html):

```
library("cyphr")

key <- cyphr::key_sodium(sodium::keygen())
x <- list(a = 1:10, b = "don't tell anyone else")

path_object <- file.path(tempdir(), "secret.rds")
cyphr::encrypt(saveRDS(x, path_object), key)

cyphr::decrypt(readRDS(path_object), key)
```

#### Hints:

- use your own filename instead of a temporary folder in the example, e.g.

```
path_object <- "d:/secret.rds"
```

- don't forget to store the key - of course on another drive ;-)